# Powershell "ExpandProperty" doesn't work when saving to CSV output

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

How do I expand the

```
 $thisPerms  = Get-Mailbox username  -ResultSize unlimited 

 Get-ADPermission $thisPerms.Identity 
           | Where {$_.ExtendedRights -like "Send-As" -and $_.User.ToString() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.Deny -eq $false}  
           | select user, ExtendedRights, identity, isinherited -ExpandProperty ExtendedRights
           | Export-Csv c:\out.csv\]
```

**Output to screen**

```
User                          ExtendedRights                Identity                                        IsInherited
----                          --------------                --------                                        -----------
domain\user                   {Send-As}                      company.com/Division/Corporate...                         False
```

**Output to text file**

*Notice how ExtendedRightIdParameter is rendered instead of the SendAs permission*

```
#TYPE Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ExtendedRightIdParameter
"User","ExtendedRights","Identity","IsInherited"
company\user","Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ExtendedRightIdParameter[]","company.com/Division/Corporate Services/User","False"
```

How do I get the CSV to contain the output of ExpandProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to convert the ExtendedRights property to string.. to do this.. use the ToString method

```
Name           MemberType   Definition
----           ----------   ----------
Equals         Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode    Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType        Method       type GetType()
ToString       Method       string ToString()
ExtendedRights NoteProperty  ExtendedRights=null
```

Comment: How did you get all the members and the member type?